# Is it worth to create a function if the code of the function is shorter than the code to save the registers it uses in the stack?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

I was programming some homework for uni and I got this question:

> Is it worth to create a function if the code of the function is shorter than the code to save the registers it uses in the stack?

Let me explain this with some code:

I was trying to return the value of a specific position inside a cubic two dimensional array using this code right here:

```
mul $v0, $a1, $a3
add $v0, $v0, $a2
mul $v0, $v0, DATA_SIZE
add $v0, $v0, $a0
```

Where:

- DATA_SIZE is the size of the data stored in the array
- $v0 is the value we want to access and return
- $a0 is the base address of the array
- $a1 is the row coordinate
- $a2 is the column coordinate
- $a3 is the length of the array (length of rows and columns which is equal because it's cubic)

I was wondering if it was worth it to make a function that does this, as the code to save $v0, $a0, $a1, $a2 and $a3 values to the stack and get back those values later is actually longer than the one inside the function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the function version, why would you save those registers to the stack?  And even if you did, say, save `$v0` to the stack, how would you return a value?  We only need to save `$s` registers to the stack, and then only if we use them in the function (`$ra`, too, but only if the function calls another function).  (Sounds to me like you're talking about the overhead of function prologue and epilogue, but, is there any chance you're thinking of saving these registers in the caller, not callee?)

Comment: Yes, I am talking about a function (several functions actually) that do need to call this function. I have to save the $a registers because both functions need to use arguments and $v0 because both functions have a return value

Comment: And if you use `$s` registers, then you end up with extra copies from `$v` and `$a` registers.  Yeah, this is why compilers do inlining.

Comment: @ErikEidt So you save the `$a` registers of the caller function to `$s` registers and then modify the `$a` registers? I am sorry if something is wrong I was supposed to have classes to learn assembly but we're quarantined and I am learning it by myself (because I still have to do homework).

Comment: Post more questions here - this forum is good if you have a specific question, also, you chat me at [codementor.io](https://www.codementor.io/erikeidt) and I'll answer any kind of questions about assembly, as I can, that forum is better for general purpose mentoring.

Comment: You can see what real compilers do on https://godbolt.org/.  Flip the compiler dropdown to MIPS gcc and use `-O3` optimization.  Use the `__attribute__((noinline,noclone))` function attribute or the option `-fno-inline-functions` so you can see both the callee and the caller's code-gen around the callsite.

Comment: (Compilers sometimes do some inter-procedural optimizations other than inlining, like noticing if a function is "pure", or for some compilers even using a custom calling convention that takes advantage of knowing the helper function doesn't destroy some registers.  Compare against just having a prototype without a definition to rule that out.)